# Testing if strip in column was successful with polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have developed a function to strip a dataset using polars. Now I want to check with a test if the strip was successful. For this I want to use the following logic. But this code is in python. How can I solve this using polars?

```
def test_strip():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'Entity': ['Entity 1 ', 'Entity 2', 'Entity 3', 'Entity 4', 'Entity 5'],
        'Table': ['Table 1', ' Table 2', 'Table 3', 'Table 4', None],
        'Local': ['Local 1', 'Local 2 ', None, 'Local 4', 'Local 5'],
        'Global': ['Global 1', ' Global 2', 'Global 3', None, ' Global 5'],
        'mandatory': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'CM ', 'M']
    })
    job = first_job(
        config=test_config,
        copying_list=copying,
    )
    result = job.run(df)
    df_clean, *_ = result

    for column in df_clean.columns:
        for value in df_clean[column]:
            if isinstance(value, str) and (value.startswith(" ") or value.endswith(" ")):
                raise AssertionError(f"Strip failed for column '{column}'")
```

Comment: could you make your example reproducible please?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to use the following logic?  The logic you've presented is to iterate through each cell one at a time to check if the first and last character is a space.    Are you trying to work out the syntax to do exactly that in polars or do you just want a filter expression to find values that begin or end with a space?

Comment: I want to identify if there are whitespaces left after using the function written in polars. It does not mean it should exactly do the same as in python. It should check if the strip was succesful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it...

```
def test_strip(df):
    bad_rows=df.filter(
            pl.any([pl.col(x).str.contains("(^ )|( $)") for x in df.columns])
        )
    if bad_rows.shape[0]==0:
        return("all good")
    else:
        str_cols=', '.join(bad_rows.melt().filter(pl.col('value').str.contains("(^ )|( $)")).get_column('variable').unique().to_list())
        raise AssertionError(f"Strip failed for column(s): {str_cols}")
```

The meat and potatoes is the bad_rows assignment.  It combines a list comprehension that uses a regex with the beginning of string anchor and the end of string anchor.  That is wrapped in `pl.any` so that any column can trigger it.  If the shape is 0 that means everything worked and it returns a message stating as much.  Otherwise it'll raise the error and tell you which columns were bad.